# Have TextInputLayout only showing hint after typing the first character

Tags: android

Previously, before support library, to have floating label, I am using the following 3rd party library from Chris Banes.

https://gist.github.com/chrisbanes/11247418

The library suits me pretty well. As, it shows the floating hint, only after typing the 1st character.

### Before typing, with focus

[image]

### After typing, with focus

[image]

Here's the code being used.

```
<org.yccheok.portfolio.FloatLabelLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:floatLabelTextAppearance="@style/PortfolioFloatLabel">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/unit_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/new_buy_portfolio_unit"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoExtractUi">
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</org.yccheok.portfolio.FloatLabelLayout>
```

I decide to migrate to Google Design Support Library for better support.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/usernameWrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/unit_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/new_buy_portfolio_unit"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoExtractUi">
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

However, the floating hint will shown immediately, just after you focus `EditText`, even before typing the first character.

[image]

I was wondering, is there any way to show the floating hint, only when there is at least 1 input character at `EditText`?

Comment: I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You might want to implement a TextWatcher and set the focus manually at the desired text length.